# I cannot understand this grep pattern

Tags: bash, grep

> file="value"

here is the content of value:

first col1 col2 col3

second col1 col2 col3

three col1 col2 col3

wanted output:

first col1 col2 col3

three col1 col2 col3

condition: we work with variables not with files directly. the search pattern should be stored in a variable as well.

In order to have this result, I do:

> var=second
>
> grep -v $var $file > $tmp;mv $tmp $file

tmp must be initialized with any value in order to work

But I came accross this and I just do not understand my bash anymore:

> grep −v  "^${var},"  $file > $tmp;mv $temp $file

Apart from the fact that it does not work for me, I would like to understand the meaning or at least what it is intended to do; maybe I can arrange it after.

what does mean "^${var},"    !!??

what I know so far:

^ -> start of line

$ -> end of line

^$ -> ?

{} -> match exactly

, -> ?

all these symbols together -> ?

Any idea folks ? thank you so much.

Comment: `${}` is not grep syntax at all -- inside double quotes it's *shell* syntax, telling the shell to replace it and its contents with a variable's value.

Comment: `set -x` is your friend for seeing commands as they're actually run after expansions are complete. And there are a lot of quoting-related bugs here -- consider running your full script through http://shellcheck.net/

Comment: @achille: Please [format your code properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command is using double quotes, which means that `bash` gets to play with the argument first.

In the following:

```
grep −v "^${var}," $file > $tmp;mv $temp $file
```

...with:

```
var=foo
```

...`bash` will expand `${var}` to `foo`, resulting in:

```
grep −v "^foo," $file > $tmp;mv $temp $file
```

(it'll also expand `$file`, `$tmp` and `$temp` (?), but that's not interesting)

Comment: temp is a typo (should be tmp).

Answer (score 0):

To add to Roger's answer,

defining your variable between {} within a string indicate to bash which part is the string and which part is the variable.

For instance if you write it like this:

```
"^$var,"
```

bash will expand it this way: "^'value of variable named var,'" which would result in a blank value since the variable is var and not var, giving this end result : "^"

if you use the curly brace instead like this:

```
"^${var},"
```

bash will look for a variable var and append ^ at the start and a , at the end giving you this value after expansion "^'var value',"

so with

```
var=foo
```

you would get "^foo," as your grep pattern

Comment: @mklement0 - my apologies

Comment: temp is a typo.